# 'IObservable<SyncProgress>' does not contain a definition for 'CombineLatest'

Tags: xamarin.ios, synchronization, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I just took this code snippet from realm which fits my requirement .

```
        var session = realm.GetSession();
        var uploadProgress =  session.GetProgressObservable(ProgressDirection.Upload, ProgressMode.ReportIndefinitely);
        var downloadProgress = session.GetProgressObservable(ProgressDirection.Download, ProgressMode.ReportIndefinitely);

        var token = uploadProgress.CombineLatest(downloadProgress, (upload, download) =>
                                  {
                                      return new
                                      {
                                          TotalTransferred = upload.TransferredBytes + download.TransferredBytes,
                                          TotalTransferable = upload.TransferableBytes + download.TransferableBytes
                                      };
                                  })
                                  .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
                                  .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
                                  .Subscribe(progress =>
                                  {
                                      if (progress.TotalTransferred < progress.TotalTransferable)
                                      {
                              // Show spinner
                          }
                                      else
                                      {
                              // Hide spinner
                          }
                                  });
```

But CombineLatest method is not available inside IObservable interface in Xamarin provided .Net subset.

But given I took this directly from real websites it is supposed to work .

Comment: What's the question? have you checked realms pre-requisites etc etc. ?

Comment: Question is , "But CombineLatest method is not available inside IObservable interface in Xamarin provided .Net subset "

So i can't use above code snippet , I did read that whole article , which wanted to downloaded a package from nugget .

and include system.reactive.linq which I did

Comment: have you tried System.Reactive.Linq.Observable ?

Comment: Let me try ! will be back in a sec

Comment: there is nothing like that , I don't get any entries in further to system.reactive.linq

Comment: Then I don't think it's the right nuget package / assembly (maybe you've got an older one, or a 3rd party one). Because Observable is a core component of being able to access live merged queries.

Comment: link to that nuget package ?

Comment: Based on the documentation, then it has to be this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/4.0.0-preview00001  Couldn't find a lot about the preview, so try the preview version, then try the stable, if the preview doesn't expose the correct methods.